# What is wrong with the method of this code?

Tags: java

I have a certain doubt if the method provided in the code is correct or missing something. The code runs fine but I still think that the method is not suitable. It seems to have a bug. Here is the code:

```java
// Java  program to find an element x in a
// sorted array using Exponential search.

import java.util.Arrays;

class Test
{
    // Returns position of first ocurrence of
    // x in array
    static int exponentialSearch(int arr[], int n, int x)
    {
        // If x is present at firt location itself
        if (arr[0] == x)
            return 0;

        // Find range for binary search by
        // repeated doubling
        int i = 1;
        while (i < n && arr[i] <= x)
            i = i*2;

        // Call binary search for the found range.
        return Arrays.binarySearch(arr, i/2, Math.min(i, n), x);
    }

    // Driver method
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int arr[] = {2, 3, 4, 10, 40};
        int x = 10;
        int result = exponentialSearch(arr, arr.length, x);

        System.out.println((result < 0) ? "Element is not present in array" :
                                "Element is present at index " + result);
    }
}
```

This is the method returning the class. Am I missing some definitions?

Comment: you should not use an underscore before the private variable name, it seems like you are switching from python.
what do you mean by returning class?

Comment: No i have a bug in the "difference" method in the code above..but I am not able to find it

Comment: Pick a naming convention and stick with it. Preferably the standard Java convention. I'd recommend against the practice of prefixing member variables as well.

Comment: You are performing Set s1 - s2, so the size of the resulting set is unknown, but it may be larger than the size of s2. If you set it to size2, it may not have enough space.

Comment: Hi @Alex, thanks for your answer, can u be a little more verbose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `difference()` method is basically logical correct. It will create a new `OrdSetSimple` with the elements in s1 with is not in s2.

However, take the example below.

```
s1 = [2, 3, 5]
s2 = [3]
```

The resulting set to be

```
result = [2, 5]
```

You can see that the size of the result is 2, while size of s2 is 1.

From your code, you set the size of the resulting set as size of s2.

```
OrdSetSimple set = new OrdSetSimple(size2);
```

which may result in not able to add all resulting elements to the result.

Try change the code to

```
OrdSetSimple set = new OrdSetSimple(size1);
```

which use the size of s1, as the size of the resulting set should be equal to or smaller than s1.